# Перенос текста из listbox в файл

Tags: c#, winforms

Следующий код переносит в файл только выделенные строки из листбокса.

```
string writePath = "file.txt";
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(writePath, false, System.Text.Encoding.Default))
{
sw.WriteLine(listBox1.Text);
}
```

Возможно ли как-нибудь перенести всё содержимое в файл?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все элементы хранятся в свойстве [`Items`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.items?view=net-5.0). Нужно будет пройтись по ним циклом:

```
string writePath = "file.txt";
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(writePath, false, System.Text.Encoding.Default))
{
    foreach(var item in yourListBox.Items) 
    {
         sw.WriteLine(item.ToString());
    }
}
```

Если `ListBox` привязан к данным, то возможно `ToString` и элементы потребуется преобразовать перед выводом.